# How can I clear 2 textareas by erasing the text on the first one using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, textarea

When I write "hola" and click on "encrypt" the result is shown in a second textarea. ¿Is there any way of clearing the text of the 2nd text area only by erasing the text in the 1st one?

[image]

I've found I can create a button but there must be a solution without creating it.

Comment: You can use a `keyup` listener in the first textarea. It can check if the value is empty, and then erase the second textarea.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Barmar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the onChange() in the first text area like

```
<textarea id="1" onChange="eraseSec" />

<textarea id="2" />

<script>
function eraseSec(){
 x = getelementbyid(1)
 y = getelementbyid(2)

 if (x.value == ""){
  y.value = ""
 }
}

</script>
```

This way when you clean the first textarea the second one will be erased

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

use Onchange() on your textarea and set it to empty if other textarea have value.